# My Boss Wants Fancier Methods

Tags: communication

I work in a young (< 3 year-old, <15 employees) startup. Our core data product is a recommendation engine. One of my primary responsibilities is to experiment different methods and prototype it. Because the company is so young with very few clients, there are not many observed data (< 1000) in our system. We heavily rely on external data source to help with feature engineering and manually labeled data for validation. My philosophy is, using the dumbest and simplest method to get the framework out first. But my boss wants "more recognized" method, using his own definition "methods that discussed by some papers, widely evaluated in the community, and have existing tested implementations we can directly use". For example, in one model I simply used mean as an performance metric, and I think it is good enough for now, but he wants a much more complicated metric "discussed by some paper". I am not arguing that what he wants isn't doable, but I am tired of explaining that, based on our current user engagement rate and amount of data we have, I really don't think that's the top priority. In a small startup like this, I wear a lot of different hats and I think I have spread too thin. I am wondering if anyone has been in the similar situation and how you dealt with it.

Comment: I was hired as the expert of the field, most time I decide the priorities on the data product. That said, when he weighs in, I also listen.

Answer (score 4):

You and your boss may both be right, from different points of view and with different objectives.

From an engineering point of view, there is a lot to be said for choosing the simplest approach you can until you have the framework done. From that point of view dumb and simple are terms of praise.

Looking at sales and financing, things that dominate the life of management in a small start-up, there may be a major advantage to being able to say "We use fancy method X, discussed in these papers.". Dumb and simple may seem much less impressive in a presentation than a method that is discussed in papers and has been widely evaluated in the community.

Comment: Funny thing you said "from an engineering point of view" haha. My boss is the CTO of the company.

Comment: @chchannn A good CTO should be a bridge between engineering and the rest of the company, and the person to bring wider considerations into engineering decisions.

Comment: Perhaps the CTO wants this single thing to be the unique selling point and he cannot imagine the framework being sold without it.

Answer (score 2):

Find out what exactly motivates your boss and then adress exactly those issues.
As theorised here, one reason could be marketing.

Your boss could name drop the google guide Rules of Machine Learning in a phrase like: We strictly follow the Google Gudie in applying Machine Learning to practical problems.

Rule 1?

> Rule #1: Don’t be afraid to launch a product without machine learning.
>
> Machine learning is cool, but it requires data. Theoretically, you can take data from a different problem and then tweak the model for a new product, but this will likely underperform basic heuristics. If you think that machine learning will give you a 100% boost, then a heuristic will get you 50% of the way there. (...)

https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/rules-of-ml

While this is not a paper, the name of Google carries a lot of weight and is likely to impress. This way, you can give your simple methods way more weight!
Maybe that's enough.

Maybe, scaleabilty is a problem.
Alas

> Rule #7: Turn heuristics into features, or handle them externally.

So, you could argue you build the building stones of your future solution.

Big Point, who decides priorities? Getting priorities spelled out explicitly and giving those to your boss to prioritize might change his view. Often people simply assume that stability/reliabilty is a given. But this can be a lot of work.
In different projects, reliabilty has different a different priority.
Maybe you think it's high, and your boss think it's low.

Maybe goodsounding solutions are more important than good solutions!
Sad, but often true. (I once in a project where everything we did was selfhosted, we were good at it and had years of experience. But for marketing reasons, we had to find a small part where we used the cloud, so our boss could claim we are in the cloud! 0 technical reasons for it.)

I dont know what else you do, but you say you are spread to thin. One of your jobs as underling is giving your boss enough transparency to enable him to make decisions. Make him aware of all the things you do and then discuss and clarify all the priority of those things. Maybe you do something that's more important, maybe you don't.
You should assume the mindset of giving your boss the implications of what things mean, but letting your boss decide. This way, he feels free and he feels he owns the decision more.
And if he decides fancy method from paper is priority #1, just be sure he understand which other things will get delayed for this. And then hack away at this!

Thee only exception I would make is if you see a topic that sinks your company if you drop it. E.g.: Adapting to legal requirements or such. But otherwise, let your boss decide.

Answer (score 0):

**I would implement the fancy and complex methods**

Statistically you aren’t going to be in that job two years from now. You are going to want a new and higher paying other job. Fancy methods look better on the resume rather than simple methods.

I face the opposite challenge. I want to do the fancier stuff but deadlines and sprints often mean quick hacks that never get resolved. A lot of us would enjoy having your problem.

Even if you don’t think you are going to move, your company probably plans to scale so wants to be prepared for that and not have to redo work. If that is part of the strategy, enforcing quality is your boss’s job. You aren’t in charge, so your philosophy comes 2nd. There could also be sales, legal, or contractual obligations related to the methods used. VCs might ask about whether best practices are in place.

Comment: I also have sprints pressure. That's another reason I don't want to set myself to fail. Also I don't see why to be able have fancy things on resume and using simple methods at my current company's scale are mutually exclusive.

Comment: CV padding is a really bad reason for doing this. Make sure your employer has their eyes open to the real costs of "fancier" methods, including the amount of time and capacity you have with other obligations within the company.

If there's a good business reason for doing them, then go for it! But if it means sacrificing something else that may provide better business value, then make sure that's understood as well. Don't just do things to get a better job in the future, do them because it was the professional thing to do for your current employer.